# Error must be convertible to a buffer, not InMemoryUploadedFile

Tags: django, python-2.7, buffer

I am trying to save a blob image (jpeg) and getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Shah/Envs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/Users/Shah/Envs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/Shah/Envs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Shah/Desktop/project/project/views.py", line 604, in thumbnail_photo
image_result.write(blob)
TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not InMemoryUploadedFile
[01/Aug/2016 12:20:55] "POST /thumbnail_photo HTTP/1.1" 500 15608
```

After doing some googling, I couldn't find a solution. I am not sure how to convert the InMemoryUploadedFile to a buffer. The relevant lines of code from the method are below.

```
    if request.FILES:
        print('files')
        blob = request.FILES['blob']
        image_result = open('what_is_happening.jpeg', 'wb') 
        image_result.write(blob)
        return HttpResponse("success")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
image_result.write(blob)
```

to

```
image_result.write(blob.read())
```

Comment: @shah happy coding!